# Process data with JSTL

Tags: javascript, jstl

I'm brand new to JSTL and have a question because I need to process some data before displaying it with HTML.

Here's my data returned from server:

```
<participantMeetingList>
    <meeting>
        <meetingName>Test</meetingName>
        <description>Description for test meeting</description>
        <startTime>2013-06-13 00:45:00.0</startTime>
        <endTime>2013-06-13 02:00:00.0</endTime>
        <creatorName>me@test.com</creatorName>
    </meeting>
    <meeting>
        <meetingName>HTML 5 lobby test</meetingName>
        <description>Description for lobby test</description>
        <startTime>2013-06-04 11:30:00.0</startTime>
        <endTime>2013-06-04 12:30:00.0</endTime>
        <creatorName>you@test.com</creatorName>
    </meeting>
</participantMeetingList>
```

I'm using this JSTL to simply render 1 row after another for each record:

```
<div id="meeting-schedule">

                        <c:forEach 
                            var="meeting" 
                            items="${response.mMeetingList}"
                            begin="0"
                            end="5">

                            <div class="row">

                                <!--  MEETING DAY AND DATE -->
                                <div class="span1">
                                    <small class="muted"><fmt:formatDate value="${meeting.startTime}" type="date" pattern="E MMM"></fmt:formatDate></small>
                                    <h2><fmt:formatDate value="${meeting.startTime}" type="date" pattern="d"></fmt:formatDate></h2>
                                </div>

                                <ul class="span4 unstyled">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#" class="row" onclick="getMeetingDetails(${meeting.meetingId})">
                                            <div class="span1"><fmt:formatDate value="${meeting.startTime}" type="time" pattern="h:mm a"></fmt:formatDate></div>
                                            <div class="span3">${meeting.meetingName}</div>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>

                            </div>

                        </c:forEach>

                    </div>
```

However, our designer now says they want one row for each date where the first td cell is the month and date and the second td cell is a list of meeting names and times.

Can I do this using JSTL? Can anyone point me in the right direction to get started, please?

Thanks for any helpful tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Java side it should be something like this

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>> outer = 
    new HashMap<String, Map<String,List<String>>>();

Map <String,List<String>> inner = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

List <String> dayMeetings = new ArrayList<String>();
dayMeetings.add("Meeting1");
dayMeetings.add("Meeting2");

inner.put("10:00", dayMeetings);
outer.put("2002-12-01", inner);
```

Then you add “outer” into response attributes, if using Spring (not necessary) this will be:

```
return new ModelAndView("meetingView", "meetings", outer);
```

On the JSP side you can put something like this without any formatting, because your web designer will add formatting

```
<c:forEach var="entry" items="${meetings}">
<c:set var="day" value="${entry.key}" />
<c:set var="dayMeetings" value="${entry.value}" />
<c:out value="${day}" />
<c:forEach var="timeMeeting" items="${dayMeetings}">
    <c:out value="${timeMeeting.key}" />
    <c:out value="${timeMeeting.value}" />
</c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 1):

My experience with JSTL showed me that it is better to put as much logic as possible on the server side.  Theoretically you can put a condition to display a date only when it changes, but this will give you logical conditions in the JSP.

I would organize the data as Map:

```
<Day, Map<day-time, meeting>.
```

So you will have the outer Map with month-date as a key, and an inner Map with time of the day as a key. Then you will have 2 loops

Outer Loop: Loop over Day. Every day will be displayed only once as your designer wants

Inner Loop: Loop over day-time. You will be displaying meeting for every time of the day

Comment: Thank you for a prompt response; My apologies, but I'm such a newbie to JSTL (coming from Flex) that I've been trying to figure out your response. For example, how do I create a Map object with a key equal to the date? I'm guessing that your code snippet isn't an exact match of what I need to do. If I can get that part done then creating the loop shouldn't be a problem for me.

Comment: Just added the code - did not test it thoroughly, in any case the actual code will be different. You will populate Maps from your data